Stops "Update your device settings" popup when there's a sport game on
A long time ago, I opted to watch the scores for one game on my phone. It allowed itself to draw over other apps, and was cool.
I want to turn this feature off, but I can't find anywhere to do so. Reportedly, it's from the Google app itself. I have denied the permissions, but every time there is a game on, I get the following popup (typed for ease of searching):

Update your device settings
Pinned matches lets you follow sports games and scores even while you
are using other apps. Turn on permit for drawing over other apps

How do I get this to stop popping up without allowing the scores to stay on?
In case it matters: Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G (SM-G781W), running Android 13.

Also posted on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/1ggthn1/how_to_stop_sports_from_wanting_to_show_up/

@AndrewT. Ya, uh, that's me... Lol
